# scala merge two maps Map[String, Long] fastest approach

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge, hashmap

I want to merge two maps in fastest possible way by grouping by key and returning sum of values

```
val m1: Map[String, Long]
val m2: Map[String, Long]
```

currently, I do:

```
(m1.toSeq ++ m2.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

What's faster approach? Would HashMap be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
val m3 = m1.foldLeft(m2) { case (accMap, (key, value)) =>
  val accValue = accMap.getOrElse(key, 0)
  accMap + (key -> (value + accValue))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have **cats** in scope, all you need is this:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

val combined = m1 |+| m2
```

Comment: but is it actualy faster? I am running it on lots of data in real time

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70686580/4111404 - Anyways, if you want the absolute fast then use a mutable map and a `foreach` but I really doubt you need that.